# Cannot call save object properly

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem which I don't know how to solve. I have a form which I use to display data and also to edit data.

```
<!-- New Network button -->
<h:button style="position:absolute; bottom:25px; right:265px;" styleClass="buttonImage" value="New Network" outcome="/Network/NewNetwork.xhtml" rendered="#{not bean.editable}"/>

<!-- Edit button -->
<h:commandButton style="position:absolute; bottom:25px; right:150px;" styleClass="buttonImage" onclick="this.disabled = true;" value=" Edit Network " rendered="#{not bean.editable}" action="#{bean.editNetwork(true)}" >
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>&nbsp;

<!-- Save Changes button -->
<h:commandButton style="position:absolute; bottom:25px; right:150px;" rendered="#{bean.editable}" styleClass="buttonImage" value=" Save Changes " onclick="editdialog(this, 'Do you want to save the changes?');
        return false;" />

<!-- Hidden Edit button -->
<h:commandButton id="editdata" value="HiddenDelete" action="#{bean.saveData}" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>

<!-- Cancel button -->
<h:commandButton style="position:absolute; bottom:25px; right:65px;" styleClass="buttonImage" value=" Cancel " rendered="#{bean.editable}" action="#{bean.initDBData}" >
    <f:ajax render="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

I use this JavaScript in order to confirm edit of data:

```
// Question Dialog for edit panel
function editdialog(button, a) {
    jQuery("<div />", {
        text: a
    }).dialog({
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                jQuery(button).closest("form").find("[id$=editdata]").click();
                //$("form\\:deleterow").click();
                jQuery(this).dialog("close");
                button.value = "Processing...";
                button.disabled = true;
            },
            "Cancel": function(event) {
                jQuery(this).dialog("close");
                event.preventDefault();
                button.value = "Save Changes";
                button.disabled = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But after checking server longs data the Java method `saveData` is never called by the JavaScript. I'm missing something which I cannot find. Can you help me to find my mistake, please.

```
EDIT:
```

The problem is here:

```
<!-- Hidden Edit button -->
<h:commandButton id="editdata" value="HiddenDelete" style="position:absolute; bottom:25px; right:650px;" action="#{bean.saveData}" rendered="#{bean.editable}">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

When I click the button the form is not submitted and the the Java method `savedata` is not called.

Comment: Did you trace JavaScript execution in Firebug?

Comment: Yes, there is any output.

Comment: Ok, so as I understand if you manually click the editdata button, the save method doesn't get called, right? So how does `bean.saveData` look like?

Comment: Yes, for some reason this is not happening - the Java method is not properly working.

Comment: Can you provide some code from the bean? Your `editable` property needs to be `true` when the form is submitted. Perhaps you're using `@RequestScoped` and the `editable` became false on each request.

Comment: This is the source code of the bean: http://pastebin.com/hfgNWYWG

Answer (score 1):

I think there are quotes missing in the jQuery selector:

```
jQuery(button).closest("form").find("[id$='editdata']").click();
```

Comment: Ok, but have you checked that the selector actually finds the button?